# PHP autoload classes from different directories

Tags: php, autoload

I have found this code that autoloads all classes within single directory, and it works pretty good. I would like to be able to extend it a bit to load classes from different paths (directories). Here is the code:

```
  define('PATH', realpath(dirname(__file__)) . '/classes') . '/';
  define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

  class Autoloader
  {
      private static $__loader;


      private function __construct()
      {
          spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoLoad'));
      }


      public static function init()
      {
          if (self::$__loader == null) {
              self::$__loader = new self();
          }

          return self::$__loader;
      }


      public function autoLoad($class)
      {
          $exts = array('.class.php');

          spl_autoload_extensions("'" . implode(',', $exts) . "'");
          set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . PATH);

          foreach ($exts as $ext) {
              if (is_readable($path = BASE . strtolower($class . $ext))) {
                  require_once $path;
                  return true;
              }
          }
          self::recursiveAutoLoad($class, PATH);
      }

      private static function recursiveAutoLoad($class, $path)
      {
          if (is_dir($path)) {
              if (($handle = opendir($path)) !== false) {
                  while (($resource = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
                      if (($resource == '..') or ($resource == '.')) {
                          continue;
                      }

                      if (is_dir($dir = $path . DS . $resource)) {
                          continue;
                      } else
                          if (is_readable($file = $path . DS . $resource)) {
                              require_once $file;
                          }
                  }
                  closedir($handle);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

then in runt in my index.php file like :

```
Autoloader::init();
```

I'm using php 5.6

Comment: Did you  have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list and expect someone else to do your job for you.

Comment: @Marc B, Yes my question is how to extend the class to scan multiple directories. I dont expect anyone to do my work. I have provided piece of code, and I need help with it. If you dont want to help, then dont waste this space, and let someone else say something smart.

Comment: We fix code, we don't write it for you, or help you design your system. That's YOUR job. you try doing something, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the other directories to the include path and if the class files have the same extension as your existing class files, your autoloader will find them

*Before* calling `Autoloader:init()`, do:

```
//directories you want the autoloader to search through
$newDirectories = ['/path/to/a', '/path/to/b'];
$path = get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR;
$path .= implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $newDirectories);
set_include_path($path)
```