# Autoloading Php file that contains multiple classes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good day guys. Please I am stucked on this problem and i want help. I have this php file that i have included multiple classes. I want to autoload those classes so that laravel can execute them. How do i go about it

The codes below can be found in app/mpower/mpower.php and the required files are in other directories nested in the mpower directory.

how do i autoload these classes so that i can use all the classes in the other subsequent files

```
<?php
require_once("mpower/dependency_check.php");

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

abstract class MPower {
  const VERSION = "1.2.0";
  const SUCCESS = "success";
  const FAIL = "fail";
  const PENDING = "pending";
}

if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3.0') >= 0) {
  define('JSON_ENCODE_PARAM_SUPPORT',   true);
}else{
  define('JSON_ENCODE_PARAM_SUPPORT',   false);
}

///define("MPOWER_SUCCESS", "success");
//define("MPOWER_FAIL", "fail");
//define("MPOWER_PENDING", "pending");

require_once("mpower/setup.php");
require_once("mpower/customdata.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout/store.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout/checkout_invoice.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout/onsite_invoice.php");
require_once("mpower/direct_pay.php");
require_once("mpower/direct_card.php");
require_once("mpower/libraries/Requests.php");
require_once("mpower/utilities.php");
```

Comment: Are you using PSR-4?

Comment: Yes Please @VictorH.Avelar

Comment: Well then you have to create namespaces, you can automatically use it, obviously when you dump-autoload.

It will be useful for you to read this http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP autoload classes from different directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663356/php-autoload-classes-from-different-directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can autoload your class through composer.json in the "autoload" section

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/mpower"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/mpower/mpower.php"
    ],
},
```

I showed 2 different ways. Please use either files, to load the file, or classmap, to load the directory. Not both.

Comment: I have tried it and i have gotten another error saying Mpower ,"which is the abstract class", not found. Classes in the required files extends that abstract class on top there.

Comment: after doing this, trying to clear all cache like `php artisan config:clear`. And try again. and add `use ClassNamespace\Class` on top your controller.

Comment: i used the files method. Now "Fatal error: Class 'MPower' not found" is now showing in the console. The console error is not allowing me to run the php config:clear command

Comment: I see. In your classes, you extend the base class already 'MPower' without namespacing it to `use App\Mpower\MPower;` I think now it's all about namespacing your classes.

Comment: Excellent. It just worked after namespacing the Mpower Class... Thank you very much.. You such as Genius +1 @EddyTheDove

Comment: Then don't forget to upvote and mark my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ernesto my solution helped you, why don't want to accept my answer?