# Lavel can't load classes

Tags: laravel

I installed someone's laravel project on my machine.  Im getting an error that says my controller file can not load a class. However, no one else is experiencing the same issue.   Here's the files related to my issues

**app/Models/Menu.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use ...etc....
class Menu extends Model implements Sortable
{
}

class MenuPage extends Model
{
}
```

**app/Http/Controller/AutomobileController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Menu;
use App\Models\MenuPage as MenuPage;
use ...etc...

class AutomobileController extends Controller
{
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
      // Both these lines give Class 'App\Models\MenuPage' not found
      $menu_items = MenuPage::where('menu_id', 6)->get()->toArray();
      //$menu_items = \App\Models\MenuPage::where('menu_id', 6)->get()->toArray();
   }
}
```

I comment that both lines where I tried to use `MenuPage` gives an `App\Models\MenuPage` not foudn error.  I looked on my other colleague's computers and those same lines work for them.

I have not modified any other code since downloading this project.

Can anyone suggest why things break on my system but not others?

---

NOTES

I noticed that my colleagues are on PHP7.3 and Ubuntu 18.04, and I am on PHP7.4 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If you're on Linux and not them It could be a a case sensitive issue. Like the folder `Models` called `models`. Or the class called `Menupage.php` instead of `MenuPage.php`

Comment: I added a note to my question saying i'm on PHP7.4 and my colleagues are on PHP7.3.  Should that make a difference?

Comment: It can cause issues but unlikely to be the PHP version for this particular error. Have you tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier i just tried the `composer dump-autoload` and issues above still exist.   Is there some file somewhere that I can edit/check to see what classes are automatically imported?

Comment: So your MenuPage class also have the namespace App\Models? I ask because from the way you show it, it looks like they are in the same file

Comment: Correct, MenuPage class has the name sspace App\Models.  Both the Menu Class and MenuPage class are in the same file.

Comment: Laravel use the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard, where you can see *The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.*. I dont know why works on php7.3 and not on 7.4, but I suspect that it may be the autoload and not the php version that is causing the problem. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686048/autoloading-php-file-that-contains-multiple-classes-in-laravel)